# Using multiple if else statements and why they loop?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type in this code it gives me a return that once I use yes for the first time, on the name, it uses that return for all of them for example: if I said my name is Justin, and I said that "Yes" it is, then say I mistyped my age, then it would not give me a chance to change it, it would say "Great!". How do I fix this? I am in 9th grade so I don't know too much about programming, sorry for the noob question. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class helloworld_main {
private static Scanner scan;

public static void main(String args[])
{

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name, age, year, yes, no, no1, no2;

    System.out.print("Please enter your name --> "); // user prompt
    name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter your age --> "); // user prompt
    age = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the year you were born --> "); // user prompt
    year = scan.nextLine();


    // Their Name
    System.out.println("So your name is... " + name + ". Right?"); // correction if name is not correct
    yes = scan.nextLine();

        if ("Yes".equals(yes)) 
        {
                System.out.println("Great!");
         } else {
                    System.out.println("Oh. Please retype it.");
                    no = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello, " + no);
         }

        // The Age
    System.out.println("The age you entered is..." + age + ". Right?");

        if ("Yes".equals(yes))
        {
            System.out.println("Great!");
        } else {
                System.out.println("OK. Please reenter your age.");
                no1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("OK, I love " + no1 + " year olds!");
        }

        // Year Born
    System.out.println("The year you were born is... " + year + ". Right?");

        if ("Yes".equals(yes))
        {
            System.out.println("Fantastic!");
        } else {
                System.out.println("Ok then, please tell me what year you were born again.");
                no2 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Cool! I know someone else born in " + no2);
        }
    scan.close();

}
```

}

Comment: In eclipse you can debug your app and step each line of code so you can see exactly what's happening.  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) on debugging java in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the user input again after you prompt for it again. Add:

```
yes = scan.nextLine();
```

after:

```
System.out.println("The age you entered is..." + age + ". Right?");
```

and:

```
System.out.println("The year you were born is... " + year + ". Right?");
```

Comment: Personally I think learning how to debug would be more useful than giving them an answer.  As you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590089/how-to-only-print-else-and-not-the-if), they are going to ask a question anytime there's a problem and not know how to find the problem themselves.